# WebRTC No function was found that matched the signature provided

Tags: webrtc

I tried this code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<video src="" id="video1"></video>
<video src="" id="video2"></video>
<textarea id="lesdp"></textarea><p id="btn">Activer</p>
</body>
<script>

    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true,video:true}, function(stream) {
        var video1 = document.querySelector("#video1")
        video1.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
        video1.play()
    }, function() {

    })

    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
    pc.createOffer(function success(offer) {
        var sdp = offer;
        alert(JSON.stringify(sdp))
    }, function error() {

    })
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log("clicked")
        var lesdp = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#lesdp').value);
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(lesdp), function(streamremote) {
            var video2 = document.querySelector("#video2");
            video2.srcObject = window.URL.createObjectURL(streamremote)
            video2.play()
        }, function() {

        })

    })
</script>
</html>
```

You can test it here: https://matr.fr/webrtc.html

Open a navigator, copy the popup offer string object, paste it into the textarea, then click "Activer" and look at the error in the console.

So when I click on the "Activer" button, it has this error:

> Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found
>   that matched the signature provided.

Please help me. I use Google Chrome to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `window.URL.createObjectURL(undefined)` which produces that error in Chrome.

`streamremote` is undefined because [setRemoteDescription](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setRemoteDescription) resolves with nothing by design.

You've only got about half the code needed to do a cut'n'paste WebRTC demo. Compare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242940/918910).