# WebRTC state checking

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I would like connect 2 devices with WebRTC on localhost. All devices have no internet access.  They are connected to a same local wifi.

I try this on React Native App.

In this context offline, do I need to trickle ICE candidates and `addIceCandidate` ? If I understund correctly, ICE candidates is for `iceServer`. But my case, `iceServer` is null (because i'm offline only, connected on same localhost wifi) :

`const configuration = { iceServers: [{ urls: [] }] };`

So actualty i exchange offer and answer, but after `setRemoteDescription` the answer, the `connectionState` stay on `checking`.

You can see my React Component :

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
  }

  state = initialState;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { pc } = this;

    if (pc) {
      this.setState({
        peerCreated: true
      });
    }

    this.setConnectionState();

    pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => this.setConnectionState();

    pc.onaddstream = ({ stream }) => {
      if (stream) {
        this.setState({
          receiverVideoURL: stream.toURL()
        });
      }
    };

    pc.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      if (this.state.initiator) {
        this.createOffer();
      }
    };

    pc.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
      if (candidate === null) {
        const { offer } = this.state;
        const field = !offer ? 'offer' : 'data';

        setTimeout(() => {
          alert('setTimeout started');
          this.setState({
            [field]: JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription)
          });
        }, 2000);
      }
    };
  }

  @autobind
  setConnectionState() {
    this.setState({
      connectionState: this.pc.iceConnectionState
    });
  }

  getUserMedia() {
    MediaStreamTrack.getSources(() => {
      getUserMedia(
        {
          audio: false,
          video: true
        },
        this.getUserMediaSuccess,
        this.getUserMediaError
      );
    });
  }

  @autobind
  async getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
    const { pc } = this;

    pc.addStream(stream);

    await this.setState({ videoURL: stream.toURL() });

    if (this.state.initiator) {
      return this.createOffer();
    }

    return this.createAnswer();
  }

  getUserMediaError(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  @autobind
  logError(error) {
    const errorArray = [...this.state.error, error];
    return this.setState({
      error: errorArray
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create offer
   *
   * @memberof HomeScreen
   */
  @autobind
  createOffer() {
    const { pc } = this;

    pc.createOffer()
      .then(offer => pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          offerCreated: true
        });
      })
      .catch(this.logError);
  }

  /**
   * Create anwser
   *
   * @memberof HomeScreen
   */
  @autobind
  async createAnswer() {
    const { pc } = this;
    const { data } = this.state;

    if (data) {
      const sd = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(data));

      await this.setState({
        offerImported: true
      });

      pc.setRemoteDescription(sd)
        .then(() => pc.createAnswer())
        .then(answer => pc.setLocalDescription(answer))
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({
            answerCreated: true
          });
        })
        .catch(this.logError);
    }
  }

  @autobind
  receiveAnswer() {
    const { pc } = this;
    const { data } = this.state;
    const sd = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(data));

    return pc
      .setRemoteDescription(sd)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          answerImported: true
        });
      })
      .catch(this.logError);
  }

  /**
   * Start communication
   *
   * @param {boolean} [initiator=true]
   * @returns
   * @memberof HomeScreen
   */
  @autobind
  async start(initiator = true) {
    if (!initiator) {
      await this.setState({
        initiator: false
      });
    }

    return this.getUserMedia();
  }
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

No `iceServers` is fine on a LAN, but peers must still exchange at least one candidate: their *host* candidate (based on their machine's LAN IP address).

Either:

1. Trickle candidates using `onicecandidate` -> signaling -> `addIceCandidate`  as usual, or
2. Out-wait the ICE process (a few seconds) before exchanging `pc.localDescription`.

It looks like you're attempting the latter. This approach works because...

#### Trickle ICE is an optimization.

The signaling (trickling) of individual ice candidates using `onicecandidate`, is an optimization meant to speed up negotiation. Once `setLocalDescription` succeeds, the browser's internal *ICE Agent* starts, inserting ICE candidates, as they're discovered, into the `localDescription` itself. Wait a few seconds to negotiate, and trickling isn't necessary at all: all ICE candidates will be in the offer and answer transmitted.

#### Your code

From your `onicecandidate` code it looks like you're already attempting to gather the `localDescription` after ICE completion (and you've written it to work from both ends):

```
pc.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
  if (!candidate) {
    const { offer } = this.state;
    const field = !offer ? 'offer' : 'data';

    this.setState({
      [field]: JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription)
    });
  }
};
```

In the offerer side you've correctly commented out the equivalent code in `createOffer`:

```
pc.createOffer()
  .then(offer => pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
  .catch(this.logError);
// .then(() => {
//   this.setState({
//     offer: JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription)
//   });
// });
```

But on the answerer side, you have not, and that's likely the problem:

```
createAnswer() {
    const { pc } = this;
    const { data } = this.state;

    if (data) {
      const sd = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(data));

      pc.setRemoteDescription(sd)
        .then(() => pc.createAnswer())
        .then(answer => pc.setLocalDescription(answer))
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({
            offer: JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription)
          });
        })
        .catch(this.logError);
    }
  }
```

This means it sends an answer back immediately, before the answerer's *ICE agent* has had time to insert any candidates into the answer. *This is probably why it fails.*

**On a side-note:** Nothing appears to wait for `getUserMedia` to finish either, so answers likely won't contain any video either, depending on the timing of your `getUserMediaSuccess` function, which fails to add any tracks or streams to the connection. But assuming you're just doing data channels, this should work with my recommended fixes.

Comment: Hi jib ! Thank you for your very good post. I've try with your recommended fixes, but i've same result, initiator stay on checking state. I've edit my first post. I noticed that the state answerer side never change : always stay on `new`, maybe the problem ?

Comment: I've continued my test. I found that once the offer was imported on the answer side, `pc.signalingState` changed from` stable` to `have-remote-offer` for 1 second, then back to` stable`. I do not know if the problem comes from the offer or the generation of the answer :/ The phones are on the same wifi connection sharing :/

Comment: That sounds normal for `signalingState`.

Comment: Arf, I thought the problem was there ^^

Comment: Maybe my cut'n'paste demo in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242940/918910) will help.

Comment: Thank you. You don't use `new RTCSessionDescription` when you import offer and answer ?

Comment: @s-leg3ndz It shouldn't be needed anymore in modern browsers.

Comment: Mmmm ok, in `react-native-webrtc` module i've an error without `new RTCSessionDescription`. Maybe the last webrtc version in not upgrade :/

Comment: That's entirely possible. Just add back in then.

Comment: Is it possible https problem ? I run my app on real android device, maybe is the problem ?