# WebRTC connection between peers connected on localhost 127.0.0.1

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, rtcpeerconnection

I have slightly different usecase here. I want to do a webrtc connection between two peers running on the same host. My hardware has no connectivity (no WiFi, Ethernet), only interface I have is a lo (127.0.0.1). I am doing signaling using direct function calls between two peer processes.

From peer1 I am able to generate an offer and send it to peer2. peer2 is able to set the remote SDP and I am getting SetSessionDescriptionObserver::OnSuccess() callback, but WebRTC is not generating any ICE candidate on any of the peer. I looked at the configurations but I couldn't find anything matching to my usecase.

Is this a valid usecase, should it work?

One observation is, if I connect my hardware to a WiFi (with/without internet access), everything works.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589501/webrtc-state-checking/53601035#53601035).

Comment: Thanks, I am getting IceGatheringComplete state without getting any candidates, not even the host candidate. Looks like 'lo' interface is ignored while generating ice candidates.