# Media object doesn't respond to cookie containing object

Tags: javascript, object, video, cookies, media

Sorry if the question is very stupid
I am trying to show the stream from a person to another user using js

I have tried putting it in a cookie but it doesnt work even then.Even when the object in video is the same as the other

**File 1**

```
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
var x=document.cookie
console.log(x)
video.srcObject = x;
```

**File 2**

```
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      document.cookie=video.srcObject 
      console.log(stream,video.srcObject)
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
console.log(stream,video.srcObject)
}
```

I would like to just for now show it on two pages but for future what language should i use to store the video if you know you can share it

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is not a centralized universal camera access repository on the web. Thank goodness.

A `MediaStream` is a local resource object representing active camera use, not a shareable [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

This object lives solely in your local JS page, and isn't addressable on the web.

Since it doesn't live on any server, transporting the graphical bits from your camera to a friend's system, requires quite a bit of heavy lifting. This includes establishing an *RTCPeerConnection* which is the domain of [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling):

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
  .then(function (stream) {
    const iceServers = [{urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}];
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers});

    for (const track of stream.getTracks())
      pc.addTrack(track, stream);

    /* lots of other WebRTC negotiation code */
```

You'll also typically need a server of some kind, both to solve [discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29056385/918910), i.e. point of contact, as well as a web socket server to exchange critcal offer/answer session descriptions that are necessary for connection establishment, between the two peers.

Perhaps the simplest proof of concept is [this cut'n'paste demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242940/918910), which let you and a friend exchange the required WebRTC offer/answer session descriptions manually, letting you establish a connection without any server, to see and talk to each other.

That has about a 70% chance of working. If you're both behind symmetric NATs (most mobile networks), then it gets harder still (you'll need a TURN server, which costs money).